# What is better to use for big swap as an extension of RAM: SSD or 15k HDD (Cheetah)?

Tags: ssd, hard-drive, swap

I need to hugely extend RAM in the platform I can't do it. As a temporary solution I want to use swap for it. What is better to use for swap storage - an SSD or 15k HDD like Cheetah? I understand that anyway it'll be slower than RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disclaimer: i've never tried it.

gut feeling tells me ssd will do a better job and ... will die much sooner in the process - it offers much higher number of i/o's per second than physical hard drive [even if it's 15k rpm it's still 250 seeks/sec vs thousand or more]. but... hard drive will have much smaller addressable block - probably 512B, while ssd will have to erase 16-64kB even if single bit is changed in the swapped page.

Comment: Your gut feeling is right. It has higher IO bandwidth and a TON more IOPS so it is better. That said ;) It sucks still - more ram is the better solution.

Comment: He, you're completely right! My MacBook Pro loves using ~6GBs of swap (I have 8GBs of RAM already in here) on my SSD and things work much smoother  than if I tried to do that on a hard drive. Or if the OP has the money, I'd put two SSDs in RAID and it'll scream. :P

Comment: "will die much sooner in the process" - This is no longer true of SSDs.  Any modern one should outlast HDDs if they work at all - due to wear-levelling.

Comment: No, wear-levelling is unrelated to TRIM and doesn't require any support from the OS or controller.  It's implemented by the SSD.  It cannot be disabled as it is fundamental to how the drive operates on a low level.  Any brand-name SSD bought in the last 3 years will do it internally.

Answer (score 3):

The SSD will do a better job than a single 15k disk. Can you provide some numbers, though? Have you already exhausted the swap on your system?

If the need to extend RAM on the platform is important enough for you to care about SWAP performance, then it's probably important enough to obtain the right amount of RAM.

Comment: I'm not able to increase RAM due to motherboard limiations (it's a desktop and I already installed 16GB) and using swap brings at least ~100 (or more) GB of extra memory.

Comment: Before you paint yourself in the corner, you need to prioritize obtaining a server class board - it'll be worth it versus having a scratch disk for swapping ...